# Как сделать анимацию, чтобы она начала работу при hover, и если убрать курсор все равно отработала полностью?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
@keyframes rotate-romb {
 0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
 15%  { transform: rotate(-15deg); }
 60% { transform: rotate(90deg); }
 100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes rotate-square {
 0%   { transform: rotate(45deg); }
 15%  { transform: rotate(30deg); }
 60% { transform: rotate(135deg); }
 100% { transform: rotate(45deg); }
}

.about-us-box:hover .animation-border-box{
   animation: rotate-romb 1s ease;
}

.about-us-box:hover .about-us-border-img{
  animation: rotate-square 1.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: думаю тут нужен джс

Comment: на js можно, но это чревато тем, что если навести курсор , убрать курсор и снова навестись, то второй hover не сработает, пока предыдущая анимация не отработает

Comment: Алексей, а можете подсказать код примерно? типа if (.class:hover){animation=true}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока приложу пример на *Jquery*, потом на чистом *Javascript*, если сами не догадаетесь как переделать.

```js
$(".about-us-border-img").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("animated");
    $('.animation-border-box').removeClass("animated");
    // или 
    //$('.animation-border-box, .about-us-border-img').removeClass("animated");
})

$(".about-us-box").hover(function() {
    $('.animation-border-box, .about-us-border-img', this).addClass("animated");    
})
```

```css
.about-us-box {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.about-us-border-img img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@keyframes rotate-romb {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  15% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-square {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  15% {
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}


/* ключевая привязка */

.animation-border-box.animated {
  -moz-animation: rotate-romb 2s ease;
  -webkit-animation: rotate-romb 2s ease;
  animation: rotate-romb 2s ease;
}

.about-us-border-img.animated {
  -moz-animation: rotate-square 2.5s ease;
  -webkit-animation: rotate-square 2.5s ease;
  animation: rotate-square 2.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="about-us-box">about us
    <div class="animation-border-box">animation-border-box</div>
    <div class="about-us-border-img"><img src="https://olxua-ring08.akamaized.net/images_slandocomua/401251372_6_644x461_myagkaya-igrushka-kotik-mini-antistress-ugolek-_rev006.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Суть в том, чтобы повесить событие `hover` на блок и добавлять нужным элементам класс `animated`. При этом вешаем события `webkitAnimationEnd/mozAnimationEnd/animationEnd`, которые отслеживают конец анимации. На данный момент событие привязано только к одному элементу `$(".about-us-border-img")`, так как его время анимации наибольшее, а, значит, анимация другого элемента должна подождать её.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const box = document.getElementById('about-us-box');
const el = document.getElementById('animation-box');

box.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
if (el.classList.contains('anim')) return;
el.classList.add('anim');
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    el.classList.remove('anim');
    clearTimeout(timer);
}, 1000);
})
```

```css
#about-us-box {
width:60px;
height:60px;
background: grey;
}
#animation-box {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
background: red;
}
#animation-box.anim {
animation: rotate 1s ease;
}
@keyframes rotate {
 0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
 15%  { transform: rotate(-15deg); }
 60% { transform: rotate(90deg); }
 100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<div id="about-us-box">
  <div id="animation-box"></div>
</div>
```